# Given that $E[X_1]≥E[X_2]$, can we say $P[X_2≤C]≥P[X_1≤C] $?

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two random variables defined over the same domain $\mathcal{D}$. Let $C \in \mathcal{D}$ be a constant.

Given that $E[X_1] \geq E[X_2]$, then does the following assertion hold for any particular type of probability distribution over $X_1$ and $X_2$ or any particular subset of $C$:
$$P[X_2\leq C] \geq P[X_1 \leq C]$$

where E stands for expectation and P for probability.

Thanks!

Comment: No -- except if $X_1$ and $X_2$ have values in the same two-points set $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! It is indeed part of the initial assumption that $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same domain or, in other words, have values in the same point set {a,b}. But my question is whether this assumption is enough for the assertion to hold?

Comment: Yes, since, for every random variable $X$ with values in the pair $\{a,b\}$, $E(X)=a-(b-a)P(X=a)$ is a decreasing function of $P(X=a)$ and because, for every such random variable $X$, $P(X\geqslant c)$ is either $0$ or $P(X=a)$ or $1$. (Note: How comes these crucial parts of the problem were not mentioned in your question?)

Comment: In general, assuming that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are integrable, we only know that there is such a $C$.

Comment: @Did: My apologies but I think I made an error in my response to your first comment! The assumption is not that the domain of the random variables is the two-points set {a,b} but rather, it is the range [a,b].

Comment: Then there is no way that $E(X)\geqslant E(Y)$ could imply $P(X\leqslant c)\leqslant P(Y\leqslant c)$ for every $c$. Even random variables with three values provide counterexamples.